# Is there a way to automatically reply in HTML format?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I know that Outlook 2010 (and possibly all versions before and after) have no option to automatically reply to emails in a specific format.  Instead, it forces you to reply in the format of the original email.

I am not sure why it does this, though.  If you send an initial email in HTML format to someone with a text-base client, they're still able to receive the email.  When you reply to an email in text or RTF format, you're still able to manually change it to HTML and *they will still get the email*.

Is there some macro that can be used to force HTML format in all compositions, be they brand new or a reply?

**Edit:**  For those wondering why I want to change the format to HTML when it's just going to be changed to text or RTF on the send, it's because of how attachments are treated.  If the email being composed is in RTF format, dragging an attachment into the email drops the attachment into the body itself.  It does it inline, too, so the attachment can break apart a paragraph unless you're careful where you drop it.  If the format is text or HTML, it displays the attachment in the header of the email which keeps it out of the body of your email.

I've already asked how to keep this attachment quirk from happening once and the given answer was to change the format to HTML during composition.  However, it's an inconvenience to have to do this every time, especially since you don't realize you have to do it until after you've already dragged a file into the body of your email and wrecking it eight ways from Sunday.

Comment: Its even a little more pernicious than that. By default outlook infers other users preferences by the emails they send to you, and stores that in the address book entry related to that address. as such, if they send you a txt email, from then on, any time you add them as a recipient, the format downscales to txt-only.

Comment: @FrankThomas It may downscale to text, but only on the send.  I can still change the format to HTML during composition.  I'll update my answer to be more specific as to why I want to do this.